# Почему сценарии в Yii2 рекомендуется определять как константы?

Tags: php, yii2

Возьмём пример из [документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios):

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    const SCENARIO_LOGIN = 'login';
    const SCENARIO_REGISTER = 'register';

    public function scenarios()
    {
        return [
            self::SCENARIO_LOGIN => ['username', 'password'],
            self::SCENARIO_REGISTER => ['username', 'email', 'password'],
        ];
    }
}
```

В примере выше сценарии определены как константы:

```
const SCENARIO_LOGIN = 'login';
const SCENARIO_REGISTER = 'register';
```

Инициализируем мы их одним из следующих способов:

```
// scenario is set as a property
$model = new User;
$model->scenario = User::SCENARIO_LOGIN;

// scenario is set through configuration
$model = new User(['scenario' => User::SCENARIO_LOGIN]);
```

---

### Вопрос

Почему не делается так ...

Сценарии определяем в виде обычных строк:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class User extends ActiveRecord
{    
    public function scenarios()
    {
        return [
            'login' => ['username', 'password'],
            'register' => ['username', 'email', 'password'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Инициализируем их соответственно:

```
// scenario is set as a property
$model = new User;
$model->scenario = 'login';

// scenario is set through configuration
$model = new User(['scenario' => 'login');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строки сложно анализировать и рефакторить.

Пока у вас 10 файлов, вы можете спокойно пользоваться найти-заменить, если захотите переименовать что-либо. Вы не забудете, где какие значения используются и почему (если не прошёл год). Если у вас 1000 файлов, то строка "login" может использоваться в десятках мест в десятках разных значений. Если вы захотите изменить все значения или просто найти все нужные вам использования, то у вас будут проблемы.

В случае же использования констант и нормальной среды разработки вы сможете в любой момент переименовать что угодно во что угодно или воспользоваться поиском использований константы.

Кроме того, константы уберегают от опечаток. Без констант, если вы в каком-то месте опечатаетесь, то вы будете долго гадать, что же пошло не так.

Comment: Добавлю из [документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html#triggering-events) (касательно событий, но это значения не имеет): `It is recommended to use class constants to represent event names. ... This approach has three benefits. First, it prevents typos. Second, it can make events recognizable for IDE auto-completion support. Third, you can tell what events are supported in a class by simply checking its constant declarations.`.